# Как отследить на какую activity был осуществлен переход?

Tags: activity, android

Суть задачи в следующем: на некоторые активити нельзя перейти не авторизовавшись. И если нет данных авторизации, то осуществляется переход на активити с авторизацией. А как после авторизации перейти на ту активити, на которую изначально планировалось перейти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А кто мешает в intent передать как один с параметров собственно имя нужной активити (или номер)? То есть. Проверяем, нужно ли делать авторизацию. Если нет, то просто вызываем некую функцию, которая создает активити по номеру/имени. Если нет, то вызываем активити авторизации и ей передаем этот же номер. Она, осуществив всю авторизацию, может вызвать опять ту же функцию, передав ей параметры.

Способ два. Можно воспользоваться стеком активити. Каждая активити при своем старте проверяет, нужна ли ей авторизация. Если да, то запускает активити авторизации. После того, как активити авторизации будет закрыта, систама нас возвратит на предыдущую активити. В ней нужно снова проверить авторизацию. В этой схеме главное не забыть обработать вариант, когда пользователь отказался от авториазации, а то будет замкнутый круг.

Comment: Я тоже пришел к первому варианту, его реализовываю сейчас. А вот второй я не понял

Comment: Почитайте эту статью на хабре: [Tasks и Back Stack в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/186434/). Должно проясниться.